# Excel VBA TextBox Keep Line Break

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an email using VBA in Excel. For the body of the email I am taking the value of a TextBox in the excel sheet. I have enabled multiple lines in the TextBox and have put text on the first line and have text on the line below, but when I generate the email, it takes both lines of text and puts them on the same line in the email.

I need to know how to keep the line breaks in the TextBox.

```
Sub Test1()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
            "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm"

        If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
            Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
        Else
            Signature = ""
        End If

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .Display
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & ",</p>" _
                  & "<br><br>" & ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value & _
                  .HTMLBody               
            .Attachments.Add ("")
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

[image]

Here is the TextBox1 properties
[image]

Comment: Is your text in excel wrapped or is a valid line break present (`Chr(10)`). If your text is just wrapped, the format will not carry over as it will resize accordingly. You may have to `Split` your string manually for email

Comment: I added pictures of the textbox and its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your newlines, `vbNewLine`, with HTML formatted line-breaks, `<br>`, like so:

```
With outMail
    .display
    .To = Cell.Value
    .subject = "Reminder"
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & Cells(Cell.row, "A").Value & ",</p>" _
          & "<br><br>" & Replace(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value, vbNewLine, "<br>") & _
          .HTMLBody
    .Attachments.Add ("")
    .display
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Split` your string here to sperate lines

---

```
 .HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & ",</p>" _
             & "<br><br>" _
             & Split(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value, ".")(0) &"."  _
             & "<br>" _
             & Split(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value, ".")(1) & "."  _
             & .HTMLBody
```